# Block Webpage Using Firewalld

Tags: 18.04, firewall, firewalld

I am trying to get my firewalld to block an `ip` address with the rules:

- `sudo firewall-cmd --zone=block --add-source=<ip_address/submask> --permanent`, and also adding this `richrule` to the default zone (public)
- `sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address=<ip_address> reject`, then finally I reload the rule with `sudo firewall-cmd --reload`

But still I can navigate to the sites in my browser. Obviously I am doing some thing wrong. How can I block access to any webpage using `firewalld`.

These are my zone rules set:

```
block (active)
  interfaces: enp0s3
  sources: 172.217.5.110/32 216.49.176.33/32
  services: 
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 


public (default, active)
  interfaces: docker0
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 993/tcp 995/udp 995/tcp 22161/udp 4243/tcp 22/tcp 22/udp 465/tcp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

Comment: firewall-cmd by default will only filter incoming traffic and all outgoing traffic is open from the server. To achieve that you need to add different rich rule using --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter OUTPUT xxxxxx...... -j drop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after a lot of digging I finally got it to work. It requires I add what is called a `direct rule`, so to block an ip like `216.49.176.33` the rule to add would be:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter OUTPUT 0 -d 216.49.176.33/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport=80 -j DROP

sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter OUTPUT 0 -d 216.49.176.33/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport=443 -j DROP
```

Then reload with:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

To see the added rules:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --direct --get-all-rules
```

Now remove the interface from the default zone which in my case was `public` as the rule says if:

> if my interface is associated with a zone, in this case `public` then any requests from that interface will go through since the zone has no restrictions placed on the interface.
>
> The rule used by firewalld is: When packet is received or generated, what zone matches that packet. Then the rules in that zone will be applied to the that packet to determine what happens to it.

To remove I used;

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --remove-interface=enp0s3
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

**NOTE:**

After this you will have to clear browsing data from the browser(s) involved and after that you will be unable to access that ip address and note I also used the `mask` 32 to make sure those ip's that have with multiple ip's pointing to their domain will be block.

I also Of course the `CHAIN` option can be `INPUT` to prevent in ward bound traffic as well. The option `--dport=<80|443>` is used to catch both `http` and `https` traffics.

Usage:

```
usage: --direct --add-rule { ipv4 | ipv6 | eb } <table> <chain> <priority> <args>
```